# Trying to sum values from a text file, receiving unrecognized character as output?

Tags: c, file, reader

Using C, I am trying sum up the numbers in a file. The file contains numbers such as:

```
123
456
788
...
356
```

When running the code, it properly asks for input and prints the number I enter. However, it does not sum the file, and just displays an unrecognized character symbol, like a small ?. I don't think the number is over the alloted INT_MAX_SIZE. What seems to be the issue?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {

    //Number variable to assign each line to 
    int c;
    int fds[2];
    int childid;
    int size;
    int number;
    int sum;

    printf ("Enter the number of processes to create: ");
    scanf ("%d", &number);
    printf ("You entered: %d", number);
    printf("\n");

    //File I/O operations
    FILE *file;

    //Open file for reading
    file = fopen("Project1_OS/project1_data/file1.dat", "r");

    //If file is found
    if (file) {
        //While file has data to be read
        while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
            //Print data
           //putchar(c);
            sum+=c;         


    //Close the file I/O
    fclose(file);
    }
    putchar(sum);

}
```

Comment: putchar doesn't work like that. you need printf instead

Comment: 1. `sum` is unintialised. 2. You are reading ascii characters not integers. You need to convert what you read from characters/strings to integers before summing.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you @pfannkuchen_gesicht :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first `getc` it's a function for reading characters from a file not integers .
you have to use `fscanf` :

```
fscanf(file,"%3d",&c)
```

second `putchar` it's a function for printing characters  not intgers .
so you have to write :

```
printf("%d",sum);
```

Comment: It seems printf is all that needed to be changed. Thanks!

Comment: @levijoraan actually you need the scanf() change as well if you care about accurate and expected results.

Comment: @pfannkuchen_gesicht do you mean fscanf() ?

Comment: @pfannkuchen_gesicht how to get a correct answer icon ? here in stackoverflow ?

Comment: the one who asked the question has to mark you answer as the one he accepts. Some people unfortunately forget or just don't care though.

Comment: @levijoraan i need this correct mark to get more points to have the right to comment and such things !!

Comment: @pfannkuchen_gesicht It is only returning 1000 when I use that (which is the number of lines instead of the value)

Comment: @pfannkuchen_gesicht try to add a "\n" in fscanf ?

Comment: Note: you are committing *coding malpractice* if you fail to validate the *match count* when using and of the `Xscanf` family of functions. (e.g. `if (fscanf(file,"%3d",&c) != 1) { /* handle error */ }` )